# PHP not displaying unordered list

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP program that is supposed to print customer purchase history after selecting the customer name from a dropdown menu. However, after selecting a customer, the unordered list that is supposed to be displayed, is empty.

**Here is my code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="customerselect.js"></script>
<?php
include "connecttodb.php";
include "getcustomer.php";
?>
<h1>Customers</h1>
<br> 
<a href="customers.php">Customers</a> 
<a href="products.php">Products</a>
<br>

<hr>
<hr> 

Select the customer whom you'd like to see what items they've purchased: 
<form action="" method = "post">
<select name="pickacustomer" id="pickacustomer">
<option value="1">Select Here</option>
    <?php
    include "getcustomername.php";  
    ?>
</select>
</form>
<hr>
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['pickacustomer'])){
            include "connecttodb.php";
            include "getcustomerinfo.php";  #This is the line that I expect to print my customer purchase history
        }
    ?>
<hr>
<br>
<br>
<h2>List of all Customers</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

**getcustomerinfo.php**

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "xxx", "xxx") or die("Not connected");
$whichCustomer = $_POST["pickacustomer"];
$query = "
SELECT c.firstname
     , c.lastname
     , p.description
     , u.quantitybought 
  FROM purchased u 
  JOIN customer c
    ON u.customerid = c.customerid
 JOIN products p
    ON u.productid = p.productid
 WHERE c.firstname = ". $whichCustomer.";";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if (!$result) {
    die("databases query failed - getcustomerinfo.php.");
}

echo "<ul>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "<li>" . $row["firstname"] . $row["lastname"]. $row["description"]. $row["quantitybought"]. "</li>";
}

echo "</ul>";


mysqli_free_result($result);
?>
```

**customerselect.js**

```
window.onload=function(){
    prepareListener();
}
function prepareListener(){
    var droppy;
    droppy = document.getElementById("pickacustomer");
    droppy.addEventListener("change",getCustomer);
}
function getCustomer(){
    this.form.submit();
}
```

I know that the query in getcustomerinfo.php works because if I enter an actual customer name, it'll display it. However, when I try to dynamically assign a name to it, the program fails to display the proper information. Please excuse how poorly this code is written as I'm just starting to learn PHP.

Comment: Maybe add some `''` around the name in the query? here: `"...WHERE customer.firstname = ". $whichCustomer.";"` should be  `"...WHERE customer.firstname = '". $whichCustomer."';"`

Comment: Looks like a good opportunity to start using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)!

Comment: I've edited my comment and added a 'should be:'

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the suggestion but adding the `''` didn't seem to work.

Comment: Does loading `getcustomerinfo.php` directly work? Does the request get submitted as expected, and the POST field is present?

Comment: Yes, loading it directly works and the POST field is present.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user3783243 reminding me to double check the POST field, I realized that I was receiving the customerid rather than the customer.firstname in the POST field. So in getcustomerinfo.php, the query should be edited like so: `...WHERE customer.customerid...` rather than `...WHERE customer.firstname...`